# Join parent to child node in hierarchical table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have the following SQL for grabbing a tree node and it's parent:

```
SELECT 
        c.id
    ,   c.tag
    ,   (
            SELECT 
                    s.id
            FROM treeTable s 
            WHERE s.lft < c.lft AND s.rgt > c.rgt
            ORDER BY s.rgt - c.rgt ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS parent
FROM treeTable c;
```

The problem though is that I also want `s.tag` inside the table, but I can't select two columns from wtihin the subquery. How can I go about refactoring this SQL to be able to select two columns?

I've looked at a lot of resources on possibly trying a LEFT JOIN, but can't get anything to work. I cant think of a simple grouping operation either due to needing to use ORDER BY and LIMIT within the subquery

EDIT: The structure of the table looks as follows:

```
Field     Type              Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
--------  ----------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
id        int(10)           (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references                    
tag       varchar(255)      latin1_swedish_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
lft       int(11)           (NULL)             NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
rgt       int(11)           (NULL)             NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using two inefficient sub selects

```
SELECT 
c.id,
c.tag,
(
    SELECT 
        s.id
    FROM treeTable s 
    WHERE s.lft < c.lft AND s.rgt > c.rgt
    ORDER BY s.rgt - c.rgt ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS parent, 
(
    SELECT 
        s.tag
    FROM treeTable s 
    WHERE s.lft < c.lft AND s.rgt > c.rgt
    ORDER BY s.rgt - c.rgt ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS parent_tag
FROM treeTable c;
```

It seems logically correct. Can't test it sorry. In these case, if you really do use this often, you should re-factor and design a table with better defined parent-child links

Comment: This solution is inefficient, the table I'm querying from has millions of entries and is continually increasing. I don't want to have two subqueries for each query. Telling me to re-factor the design is not a valid answer either, as the table perform exceptionally well for what it is designed as. 

I appreciate your willingness to help though, thanks!

Comment: I fully understand. The difficulty in your case stems from the fact that your linking with a range and using a trick (LIMIT 1) to get the top result for what should be a JOIN in most cases. I originally wrote a JOIN version with a MIN for distance (s.rgt - c.rgt) but it was not guranteed to get the s.id and s.tag .... Hope you do find a solution.